# Calculations and rendering in MATLAB, GUI in Anything Else

Tags: windows, matlab, interop

In the Hebrew University in Jerusalem there are a few MATLAB applications, consisting of both calculations and UI. Since the UI is becoming increasingly complex, it's getting very hard to maintain it.

What I'd like to do is keep the calculations and the rendering of 2D and 3D graphs in MATLAB, but control the entire UI from elsewhere. I know MATLAB exports a COM interface, which is OK for using MATLAB calculations, but I couldn't find a way to pass rendered data (MATLAB plots, basically) back through it.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* thing for you to do would be to issue an instruction to MATLAB to create the plot (perhaps creating it offscreen, to avoid an unwelcome popup window), adjust its appearance and size, then save it to an image file. Pass the filename back, then load it in from your UI code and display it.

However, that will not of course get you a plot that is "live", so you won't be able to edit it, or click on it/interact with it, or even resize it nicely.

If you need that, I'm afraid there's no documented or supported way to do it. But if you're willing to go undocumented, then MATLAB also has a Java interface (jmi.jar) that you can call from Java, and you can embed a live MATLAB plot within a Java GUI, attaching MATLAB or Java callbacks to plot elements.

Note that that capability is completely undocumented, and may well change from release to release without warning. If you'd like to learn how to approach that, I'd recommend reading through the blog [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com), and probably buying a copy of the book by that blog's author.

Comment: I think I'd prefer transferring the raw data and rendering the plots on the GUI side. I'll need to choose an environment that has comparable plotting capabilities (if I didn't need a lot of 3D rendering, Python's matplotlib would have been excellent).